# What is the purpose of using depth in JSON encode?

Tags: php, json

I have this **example** code:

```
$array = array(

    'GiamPy' => array(
            'Age' => '18',      
            'Password' => array(
                    'password' => '1234',
                    'salt' => 'abcd',
                    'hash' => 'whirlpool'
            ),  
        'Something' => 'Else'
    )

);

echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

I have seen in the PHP documentation that, since PHP 5.5.0 (thus recently), `json_encode` allows a new parameter which is the **depth**.

1. What is its purpose?
2. Why would I ever need it?
3. Why has it been added in PHP 5.5.0?

Comment: Since the documentation on this parameter is pretty sparse, I think it's a decent question. One that could be answered with a little experimentation, but nonetheless decent.

Comment: You will need it of you have more than 512 nested arrays, and you want to keep those in the resulting JSON.

Comment: I guess it is to prevent going out of the memory when encoding object with not obvious recursion.

Comment: @deceze Which is why I am wondering why I have received two downvotes. I've made sure that a question like this wasn't answered already, and I found nothing interesting in Google/PHP documentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The option limits the depth that will be processed (d'uh). The depth of an array is measured by how deep it is nested. This is an array of depth 1:

```
array(
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'baz'
)
```

This is an array of depth 2:

```
array(
    array(
        'foo'
    ),
    array(
        'bar'
    ),
    array(
        'baz'
    )
)

// ------ depth ------>
```

If the input surpasses the maximum depth (by default 512), `json_encode` will simply return `false`.

Why you may use this is debatable, you may want to protect yourself from inadvertent infinite recursion or too much resource use. An array which is deeper than 512 levels *probably* has infinitely recursive references and cannot be serialised. But if you are sure your array is not infinitely recursive yet is deeper than 512, you may want to increase this limit explicitly. You may also want to lower the limit as a simple error catcher; say you expect the result to have a maximum depth but your input data may be somewhat unpredictable.

Comment: Why would someone _ever_ need to have 512 depth in an array? That's.. insane, right? But also numbers like 50, 60 or 70 are insanely high, aren't they?

Comment: Exactly, you'll probably *never* have an array 512 deep, so it's a pretty safe default upper limit. I guess this has always been the internal limit used by `json_encode` as a way to prevent infinite recursion. In 5.5 this parameter has simply been exposed to you and you can now change it if you wish. Probably somebody ran into this limit and needed it increased. Consult the PHP source code commit history if you're really interested in why this parameter has surfaced now.

Comment: Seems this is the ticket that spawned the change: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62369

Comment: @deceze, or maybe someone found they needed a _lower_ limit due to resource issues.

Comment: The array can be maximum in depth from 2 to 10, 512 is equals to infinite in the sense of depth. Thanks @deceze