# PHP json_decode() depth meaning

Tags: php, json, decode

I'm saving some JSON and I don't know if this might later nib me in the butt if the JSON gets too big(The size depends on user input), though from my reading the max depth of 512 seems to be quite a high number and not really practical, but it triggered something in my mind and I've only now realized that I don't quite understand the meaning of "depth" of an array or how to count it (visually)...

I checked out this question while trying to get a clear understanding of depth: [What is the purpose of using depth in JSON encode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938207/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-depth-in-json-encode/20938305#20938305)

And the example given was:

```
array(
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'baz'
)
// Has depth of 1

array(
    array(
        'foo'
    ),
    array(
        'bar'
    ),
    array(
        'baz'
    )
)
// Has depth 2
```

But what about...

```
array(
    array(
        'foo'
    ),
    array(
        'bar'
    ),
    array(
        array(
               'baz' => 'caz'
    )
)
```

Or

```
array(
        array(
            'foo'
        ),
        array(
            'bar'
        ),
        array(
            array(
                   'baz' => 'caz'
        ),
        array(
            'tree' => array(
                     'tree-a' => array(
                                'car-a' => 'car-b'
                                 )
                     )
        )
    )
```

I know this might be obvious to some but it's just one of those things I never thought much about. I did check out the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for `json_decode()` and it's depth parameter but still couldn't wrap my head around it. Maybe there's some rule of thumb i can use?

I'm trying to understand this in the context of when using json_decode();

Comment: `$json[0][1][2]` has a depth of three (array nesting levels).

Comment: @mario I can see that from what you wrote...but I don't quite get it from php.net example nor in the two last examples i wrote above...Is the depth still 2? or is it now 4?

Comment: It's always about the deepest element. For example, the depth of `[1, 2, 3, [[[[4]]]]]` is 5.

Comment: @RoboRobok Thank you for commenting, so in the last example above, the depth of that array is 4 right?

Comment: Yes. And if the maximum depth is exceeded, `json_decode()` returns `NULL`.

Comment: The examples become clearer and more understanble if you rewrite them with short array syntax. (Then PHP and JSON are pretty much alike.)